# Shouldn't 'mark favorite' give the same reputation as an up vote? Or even more?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bookmarks

I suggest that marking a question as favorite should give at least as much reputation to the writer than upvoting the question...  After all, if the user intends to come back to the question later, it must be that this question is interesting, no?

Comments?

Comment: To the several people who down voted this: which is this question unclear or not useful and why?

Comment: Voting and favoriting are not mutually exclusive.  Also, you can't favorite an answer, so a lot of people favorite the question (even though the question may be low quality), in order to find the answer again.

Comment: I agree with fixer1234, the favourite is for the entire post, not necessarily for the question.  Maybe a badge for 50 post getting favourited would be good.

Comment: @RohitGupta Something [like](http://superuser.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question) [these](http://superuser.com/help/badges/34/stellar-question)?

Answer (score 10):

**No**

I use favourites as bookmarks for questions I still want to answer, and once I have done so I remove the favourite flagged. The purpose of favourites is not to gain reputation, and I can't see doing so adding any value except opening up a massive avenue of abuse.